# HTML table works on all browsers except Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am making a website and I decided to fire up Internet Explorer to check out if everything works.  To my surprise, it all pretty much does.  That being said, a table that I have in place does not look right at all.  This is the HTML of the table:

```
<div id="stats">
    <center>
    <table style="width:100%;">



                    <tr>
            <td id="name">Health:</td>
            <td class="border" id="color"><font color="#0451ff">380</font><font color="#e81123">(+75)</font></td>
            <td id="name">Health per 5:</td>
            <td id="color"><font color="#7fba00">4.85</font><font color="#e81123">(+0.5)</font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="name">Mana:</td>
            <td class="border" id="color"><font color="#0451ff">250</font><font color="#7fba00">(+50)</font></td>
            <td id="name">Mana per 5:</td>
            <td id="color"><font color="#7fba00">7.1</font><font color="#7fba00">(+0.75)</font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="name">Attack Damage:</td>
            <td class="border" id="color"><font color="#e81123">47</font><font color="#7fba00">(+3.2)</font></td>
            <td id="name">Attack Speed:</td>
            <td id="color"><font color="#e81123">0.604</font><font color="#7fba00">(+1.68)</font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="name">Armor:</td>
            <td class="border" id="color"><font color="#e81123">15.5</font><font color="#7fba00">(+4)</font></td>
            <td id="name">Magic Resistance:</td>
            <td id="color"><font color="#0451ff">30</font><font color="#0451ff">(+0)</font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="name">Movement Speed:</td>
            <td class="border" id="color"><font color="#e81123">335</font></td>
            <td id="name">Range:</td>
            <td id="color"><font color="#0451ff">550</font></td>
        </tr>

                </table>
    </center>
</div>
```

and the CSS for stats is as follows:

```
#stats {
    width:480px;
    height:173px;
    background:#09090A;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:3px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
#stats table tr #name {
    width:35%;
    height:20px;

    text-align:center;
    padding-left:4px;
}
#stats table tr #color {
color:#e97900;
padding-left:2px;
padding-right:2px;
}
#stats table tr .border {
border-right:1px solid black;
}
#stats table tr td {
    width:13%;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:245%;
    font-size:14px;
    background-color:#1a1a1a;
}
#stats table tr {
        border-bottom:1px solid black;  
}
#stats table tr:last-child {
        border-bottom:0;    
}
```

In Chrome, Safari and Firefox, the tables look like this:

[image: Correctly formatted table]

which is what I want; everything across on one line nice and neat.  But on Internet Explorer all of the tables look like this:

[image: Wrong Table Format]

is there a way to force the table to format correctly in Internet Explorer?

Comment: @null I tested it on IE 10. Also I added more CSS in the post. I forgot the table styles

Comment: Hm; I am noticing that your IE screenshot has the parentheses value of Attack Speed using 4 digits. If that gets wide enough to expand to two lines, that could cause the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with your updated css, I was able to replicate and this fixes the problem

```
#stats table tr td {
    width:13%;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:245%;
    font-size:14px;
    background-color:#1a1a1a;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

in your CSS?

Comment: oh that did it. i forgot about white-space.  Thanks! Will accept answer when it lets me